# Get data for current zoom view if X and Y axis values contains string values in a Plot.ly chart

Tags: plotly

Referring to the code, in this post [Get data for current zoomed in view](https://community.plot.ly/t/get-data-for-current-zoomed-in-view/7092) in Plot.ly forum, the code helps to get the data in current zoom view if X and Y axis contains numeric value. How can we do the same for bar chart in the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nayanadas/pen/EeKPgO). Here the bar chart X axis contains string value. Is there a way to get the data from current zoom view when x or y contains string values?

```
var data = [{
   x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys', 'lion', 'tiger'],
   y: [20, 14, 23, 40, 13],
   type: 'bar'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same functionality as before, but each integer value in the x-axis represents one value in your categorical list.

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: ["giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys", "lions", "tigers"],
    y: [20, 14, 23, 40, 13],
    type: "bar"
  }
];
var gd = document.getElementById("myDiv");

Plotly.newPlot(gd, data);
function showVisibleAnimals()
{
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("visibleAnimals");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = "Visible Animals:<br />";
  var xRange = gd.layout.xaxis.range;

  if (xRange[0] < 0) {
    xRange[0] = -1;
  }

  for (
    var i = parseInt(xRange[0]) + 1;
    i < parseInt(xRange[1]) + 1 && i < data[0].x.length;
    i++
  ) {
    outputDiv.innerHTML += data[0].x[i] + "<br />";
  }
}
showVisibleAnimals();
gd.on("plotly_relayout", function() {
  showVisibleAnimals();
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='visibleAnimals'></div>
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer, so how can i get the y axis data at the same time. i have done sample to get the y axis data, can you please check my codepen link https://codepen.io/nayanadas/pen/rZMmNZ. here i'm getting incorrect y axis value from current zoom view. how to get the correct y axis values from current zoom view?

Comment: You could use the same code for the y-axis. In your codepen example you are selecting for all y-values which are within the y-axis range but they might not be within the x-axis range.

Comment: @maximillian-peters :  I have used the same code for y-axis, but the first element is not displaying and when we zoom, the div that displays y-axis values are not updating. Please check out the updated codepen : https://codepen.io/nayanadas/pen/rZMmNZ